# BETWEEN SQL Statement tossing Overflow Error - pulling records between two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ran into a problem with a query I created in Access.  I'm getting an error that simply states "Overflow" and I'm not sure what's causing huge calculations here, so I could use a little advice.  Here's the query:

```
SELECT tbPurchases.MemberID, Count(tbPurchases.[PurchaseDate]) AS NumPurchases
FROM tbPurchases
GROUP BY tbPurchases.MemberID
HAVING (((Count(tbPurchases.[PurchaseDate])) Between DateSerial(Now(),1,1) And Now()));
```

This was created using the GUI in Access.  Basically, I'm attempting to grab the number of instances a `MemberID` shows up in `tbPurchases` (yeah, I left out an "L" - fix it later) that have `PurchaseDate`'s between the first of the year and `Now()`.

Comment: `DateSerial(Now(),1,1)` -> `DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1)` ?

Comment: in HAVING you use Count, which will give you an integer.  You are comparing an integer to datetime data types.  that is likely the problem.

Comment: @smoore4 a Integer representing a meaningful date can be compared (as Datetime is a double and an integer can be between two doubles, but`Now()`is`>43853 (days since 1899-12-31), check`?CLng(Now())`in immediate window.. But if you want to refer to`tbPurchases.[PurchaseDate]` between midnight and now, just use`WHERE tbPurchases.[PurchaseDate]  Between DateSerial(Now(),1,1) And Now()`instead of your`HAVING` (you only need`HAVING with aggregates`),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean:

```sql
SELECT 
    tbPurchases.MemberID, 
    Count(*) AS NumPurchases
FROM 
    tbPurchases
WHERE 
    tbPurchases.[PurchaseDate] Between DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) And Now()
GROUP BY 
    tbPurchases.MemberID
```